# password protecting a page on Github not possible?

Tags: github, github-pages

I want to password protect a page on a site built on Github. I've researched online, but it seems it's not possible on Github...? What would you recommend that I do? help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it's not possible. GitHub Pages are public and there's no way to avoid that without using a different backend.

Comment: Is there a way to using a diff backend easily?

Comment: Depends on your definition of easy. You'll have to do some research into different backends and evaluate which ones will work for you use case. I wish I had a specific framework suggestion for you but I don't, sorry :/